# Bash script - test whether file exists

Tags: bash

How can I create a script that will check if the file provided exists, if not then create an error message.  I have below code but it is not working:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "enter file name:"
read source
file= $source
if [ -f "$file" ] && find "$file" | grep -q .
then 
    echo "the file exists."
else
    echo "the file does not exist."
fi
```

Comment: Can you please provide the error you are receiving?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what your && find statement is doing...try like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "enter file name: " source
file=$source
if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then 
    echo "the file exists."
else
    echo "the file does not exist."
fi
```

**Edit**

Also I just noticed you had a space in `file= $source` that will not work.  It needs to be `file=$source`

**Edit 2**

I'm guessing that find part was supposed to search for the file in case it wasn't in the current directory?  In which case you can do something like this (This is a sloppy script and I can't think of a good reason to use it):

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "enter file name: " source
file=$(find / -type f -name "$source" 2> /dev/null | head -n1)
if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then 
    echo "the file exists."
else
    echo "the file does not exist."
fi
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse..tried your first code and it works..just wanted to understand .kindly explain each command being used like if [[ -f "$file" ]]